# Consolidating rows into columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table similar to this:

```
 Match | Quarter | Profit
-------+---------+--------
   1   | First   | 10.00
   1   | Second  | 14.00
   2   | First   | 22.00
   1   | Last    | 11.00
   2   | Second  | 18.00
   2   | Third   | 16.00
   2   | Last    | 10.00
```

I want to achieve this:

```
 Match | First Profit | Second Profit | Third Profit | Last Profit
-------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------
   1   | 10.00        | 14.00         |0.00          |11.00
   2   | 22.00        | 18.00         |16.00         |10.00
```

In simple words consolidating the rows into one. Important that if no value is found for a quarter then result is recorded as 0.00;

Not sure how this can be achieved using a CROSSTAB func?

I've read around and have struggled to find a good answer or solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT Match
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'First' then Profit else 0.00 end) as first_profit
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'Second' then Profit else 0.00 end) as second_profit
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'Third' then Profit else 0.00 end) as third_profit
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'Last' then Profit else 0.00 end) as last_profit
FROM data
GROUP BY match
ORDER BY Match
```

Here's an example with your sample data:

```
with data as (
select
1 as match, 'First' as Quarter, 10.00 as Profit
union
select
1 as match, 'Second' as Quarter, 14.00 as Profit
union
select
2 as match, 'First' as Quarter, 22.00 as Profit
union
select
1 as match, 'Last' as Quarter, 11.00 as Profit
union
select
2 as match, 'Second' as Quarter, 18.00 as Profit
union
select
2 as match, 'Third' as Quarter, 16.00 as Profit
union
select
2 as match, 'Last' as Quarter, 10.00 as Profit
)
SELECT Match
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'First' then Profit else 0.00 end) as first_profit
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'Second' then Profit else 0.00 end) as second_profit
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'Third' then Profit else 0.00 end) as third_profit
    , sum(case when Quarter = 'Last' then Profit else 0.00 end) as last_profit
FROM data
GROUP BY match
ORDER BY Match
```